# Error 'Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi I'm getting the following error while trying to follow an example on node.js
I've added socket.io to an express solution but whenever I try to run it, I get the following error. 
After some research on similar issues, I've come to the conclusion that I might be adding something to a header in the wrong time, but I had the server up before socket.io with no issues.

Te error

```
info  - socket.io started

http.js:690
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/home/piero/dev/workspace/authentication/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:62:20)
    at next (/home/piero/dev/workspace/authentication/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:171:13)
    at /home/piero/dev/workspace/authentication/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:150:11
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

the stack

```
, "dependencies": {      
"jquery" : "1.7.3"
, "cookie" : "0.0.4"
, "dnode" : "1.0.0"
, "mocha" : "1.3.0"
, "should" : "1.0.0"
, "socket.io" : "0.9.10"
, "ejs" : "0.7.1"
, "express": "2.5.8"
, "mongodb" : "1.0.2"    
}
```

Please let me know if you see any issues in the config before I start publishing more code.
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you trying to serve the `socket.io` client code from the static middleware?

Comment: I've got the following: nocklib.createSocket( app.listen( 3000 ) );
where it does... 
createSocket: function( app ) {
  io = require( 'socket.io' ).listen( app );...
and in a .js var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost' );

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the dependencies and that seems to do the trick. I've changed express from version 2 to 3, and is now working.
No sure that's the way to go, since I don't understand what was failing, but is working now.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to calling `res.send` twice.